# How to add posts in Wordpress without admin login using xml-rpc and curl

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc, posts

I wants to add posts in Wordpress site using xml-rpc and curl OR any alternate method without logging in WP admin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer and Following code is working for me.

```
function wpPostXMLRPC ($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username,$password,$category='Uncategorized',$keywords='',$encoding='UTF-8') {

    $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

    $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

    $content = array (
        'title'=>$title,
        'description'=>$body,
        'mt_allow_comments'=>0,
        'mt_allow_pings'=>0,
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
        'categories'=>array(
            $category
        )
    );

    $params = array(
        0,
        $username,
        $password,
        $content,
        true
    );

    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost', $params);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);

    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $results;

}

$title = 'post-title';
$body = 'POST BODY WILL GOES HERE';
$rpcurl = 'http://example.com/xmlrpc.php';
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$category = 'test';

$chk = wpPostXMLRPC($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username,$password,$category,$keywords='',$encoding='UTF-8');

if($chk) {
    echo $chk;
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: is there way to create a gallery in wordpress using PHP outside wordpress ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in feature in Wordpress that allow you to [publish an article via e-mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email). Never tested it though, but it may suit your needs.

You can configure it in your site's admin, under settings > writing (URL is like `http://yourwordpresssite.com/wp-admin/options-writing.php`).

However, if you need an API, you'll find useful things in Wordpress Codex pages related to [XML-RPC support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) and [wp.newPost](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.newPost).

For a code sample, you can have a look at [this snippet](http://pastebin.com/UuhdcEWL), which seems a good basis to me.